# OpenLayers preview problem?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, openlayers-2, shapefile

I want to display a shapefile that I have made in QGIS, in the GeoServer OpenLayers preview.

When I try it, there is a strange object that appears, and I want to ask how to get rid of the strange object?

[image: layer preview display]

Comment: You need to provide a little more information, for example, how is you shape file served to OpenLayers .. Have you loaded the shape file to Qgis (or similar) to check the actual contents? If the file is served by a WMS service, is the odd shape being generated by the WMS.

Comment: I made the shape file in QGIS and no errors, the problem arises when I publish and be seen in the layer preview screen. I use WGS84 4326 projection.

Comment: So you are doing this all in QGIS?? Please update your question to reflect this ..

Comment: @MarkC My apologies for just rejecting your addition of a [tag:qgis] tag - I had interpreted "open layer" earlier as being "OpenLayers" and now I'm not sure whether this involves both QGIS and OpenLayers or just QGIS.  I think we will need to await Fauzano editing his question to clarify, but in the meantime I don't think I can undo the edit rejection so I'll just add the QGIS tag back.

Comment: No Problem, it was added as a result of his response to my comment. I asked how to elaborate on the question as well .. One Brissy Boy to another :)

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of my question, I honestly can not speak English well. when I found this forum on google i tried to ask in the forum for the first time. thank you for your friendly response :)

Comment: the issue is resolved , the error occurs because I use a different projection , I made shapefile with QGIS using epgs 32 748 and in the openlayer publish using epgs 4326. when using the same projection , the strange object was disappear. thanks :)